# Applying a style on a part of a paragraph in OpenOffice Writer

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

I'm trying to define a custom style which should apply only to a couple of words in a paragraph. When I try to apply it to them, it applies to the whole paragraph instead.

The custom style definition is:

[image: Custom style definition]

How can I create and apply a custom style definition so that it only takes effect on a part of a paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog your showing is for a Paragraph Style.  What you want is a Character Style.

Here's a link to the OO.org wiki on [how to use character styles](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Using_character_styles) and [a screencast tutorial](http://plan-b-for-openoffice.org/intro/topic/character-style-options-overview).